# Convert SQL Statement into Linq expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am quite new to linq and .net core. I am trying to calculate the next tax return date of a company as a part of my final year’s project.

1. If there is a newly made company with no tax has been made yet (means no entry in the tax table), Then add 18 months in the company’s incorporated date.
2. If the company has already paid tax, then pick the latest date TaxReturnDate from tax table and add 9 months into that to get the next TaxReturnDate.

Thats what i have tried in SQL, now i am trying to convert this sql into Linq Query, I need some help to get the desired results.

```sql
WITH
    cte_company (CompanyID, CompanyName, CompanyNumber, IncorporatedDate, TOTAL_YEARS) AS
        (SELECT
             CompanyID,
             CompanyName,
             CompanyNumber,
             IncorporatedDate,
             DATEDIFF(YEAR, IncorporatedDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS TOTAL_YEARS
        FROM tbl_Company)
SELECT
    cte_company.CompanyID,
    CompanyName,
    CompanyNumber,
    IncorporatedDate,
    TOTAL_YEARS,
    CASE
        WHEN TOTAL_YEARS > 1 THEN (SELECT
            DATEADD(MONTH, 9, MAX(TaxReturnDate))
        FROM tbl_Tax
        WHERE cte_company.CompanyID = tbl_Tax.CompanyID)
        ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, 18, IncorporatedDate)
        END AS TaxDate
FROM cte_company
```

Linq Query

```cs
IEnumerable<CompanyTaxInfo> result = 
    from c in this.AcmeDB.tbl_Company
    let TotalYears = (DateTime.Now - c.IncorporatedDate).Value.Days / 365
    let taxReturnDate = this.AcmeDB.tbl_Tax.Max(tx => tx.TaxReturnDate).Value.AddMonths(9)
    select new CompanyTaxInfo
    {
        CompanyID = c.CompanyID,
        CompanyName=  c.CompanyName,
        CompanyNumber=  c.CompanyNumber,
        IncorporatedDate= c.IncorporatedDate,
        TotalYears = TotalYears,
        TaxDate = TotalYears > 1 ? taxReturnDate :    c.IncorporatedDate.Value.AddMonths(21)
    };

return result;
```

code is throwing DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.' exception.

Please help

Comment: TotalYears is an integer.  c.IncorporatedDate.Value.AddMonths(21) is a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query =
    from c in this.AcmeDB.tbl_Company
    let TotalYears = EF.Functions.DateDiffYear(c.IncorporatedDate, DateTime.Now)
    select new CompanyTaxInfo
    {
        CompanyID = c.CompanyID,
        CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
        CompanyNumber = c.CompanyNumber,
        IncorporatedDate = c.IncorporatedDate,
        TotalYears = TotalYears,
        TaxDate = TotalYears > 1 ? this.AcmeDB.tbl_Tax
            .Where(tax => c.CompanyId == tax.CompanyId)
            .Max(tx => tx.TaxReturnDate).Value.AddMonths(9) 
            : c.IncorporatedDate.Value.AddMonths(18)
    };

return query.ToList();
```